# Filter Array in Angular 2 for specific Parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to filter an object array which looks like this

```js
{
  "value_1": [
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00",
      "value": 1
    }
  ],
  "value_2": [
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00",
      "value": 56.1
    },
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00",
      "value": 56.08
    }
  ]
}
```

for `value` and return everything for `value` which should display: `[1, 1, 56.1, 56.08]`

which is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some map, reduce-fu

```js
let obj = {
    "value_1": [{"ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00", "value": 1},
        {"ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00", "value": 1}],
    "value_2": [{"ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00", "value": 56.1},
        {"ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00", "value": 56.08}]
};

let result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key].map(ts => ts.value)).reduce((acc, value) => acc.concat(value),[]);

console.log(result);
console.log('isArray = '+Array.isArray(result));
result.forEach((item, index) => console.log(`result[${index}]=${item}`));
```

Comment: but this is no longer an array. it's a string - can you tell me how to prevent this?

Comment: result is an array. run updated code snippet and check for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a parsing function which will iterate recursive over your data-object.

something like this:

```js
parseObject(obj: any): number[] {
  const _parse = (obj: any): number[] {
    if (!obj || typeof(obj) !== 'object') return [];

    const values = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      const o = obj[k];
      if (k === 'value' && !isNaN(o)) values.push(+o);
      if (typeof(o) === 'object') values.push(..._parse(o));
    });

    return values;
  }

  return _parse(obj);
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/c4A0G6zGTa39kQNXyfhv?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

by using for-each also you can achieve your requiremnt  have a look at below snippest

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{final}}!</p>
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = {
  "value_1": [
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00",
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00",
      "value": 1
    }
  ],
  "value_2": [
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:49+00:00",
      "value": 56.1
    },
    {
      "ts": "2016-12-05T11:28:55+00:00",
      "value": 56.08
    }
  ]
};
 $scope.final=[];
angular.forEach($scope.name,function(k,v){
 
 angular.forEach(k,function(x,y){
  $scope.final.push(x.value);
});
});
console.log($scope.final);

  
});

</script>
</html>
```